# Do services in ros 2 require a seperate .srv file?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was reading this [tutorial](http://docs.erlerobotics.com/robot_operating_system/ros2/tutorials/tutorial_6) where they have created a service based server/client for adding two integers.However, they have not created the .srv files as required in ROS 1. Is it possible to mention the service type without creating the .srv files ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271083/do-services-in-ros-2-require-a-seperate-.srv-file-?/) by [Skyking](https://answers.ros.org/users/31939/skyking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2017-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS 2 still requires a proper `.srv` file, but in the case of the tutorial you link the authors are reusing an existing definition.

You can find that one in the [ros2/example_interfaces](https://github.com/ros2/example_interfaces) repository (specifically: [ros2/example_interfaces/srv/AddTwoInts.srv](https://github.com/ros2/example_interfaces/blob/abbef5ae72e45eb8621d8f46044b85a694dc080f/srv/AddTwoInts.srv)).

Note that the tutorial you link to was (as far as I can tell) quite some time ago already. ROS 2 is still being developed, so pay attention while following the steps, as things could have changed (significantly).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0